# The Angular 2 final release and the documentations "The Tour of Heroes"

Tags: angularjs, angular

Last 2 days I've been looking at the Angular 2, I'm new to it so I went straight ["the official documentation"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial) which is the Tour of Heroes example, it's ok "Just ok" tutorial and I followed the steps and I could understand a lot from it, when I reached the HTTP part and how to get access to Data sources issues started to pop up, I'm not sure if it's me very beginner in this OR the documentation is not up-to-date with the final release, :/ Google people, a big company and you guys can not assign this task to a team who take care of the documentation and keeps it updated with the releases? My opinion it's such task is mandatory for some reasons and it's the company responsibility or the Angular 2 project team's responsibility, it's new release and it's completely different from the angularjs 1.x so don't you guys think that you should provide solid reliable support in the form of up-to-date documentation right? Unless you want React to be in the lead ;)

If anyone knows good documentation for http and how to retrieve modify save and delete data and it's compatible with the final release please share it, now the issue that I collided with in the Tour of Heroes tutorial is that I get error because of this line:

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
```

can't find the module 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'

I was ok I'm not gonna use this in memory web Api, so I created asp.net web Api and it works fine and here is the GetHeroes method in the Heroes Controller it's so straight forward:

```
  // GET: api/Heroes
    public IQueryable<Hero> GetHeroes()
    {
        return db.Heroes;
    }
```

of course I test the method and it returns all the heroes so the api working just fine, now this's the method from the hero.service.ts :

```
getheroes(): Promise<Hero[]> 
 {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
  }
```

ok I get no errors but data is nt showing like literally nothing however when I remeove .data as Hero[] part I get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81gx.jpg)
and once I click on "one hero" I get nothing as well and the url like this : 4200/details/undefined notice instead of the hero Id I get undefined ?! anyway I noticed that in many videos of some people "tutoring" angular 2 that there is no common steps to work Http for accessing data and doing CRUD operation through api , every one doing it in different way and the thing is when I try to follow it's just not working with what I have and this's from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
"codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.5",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.13.0",
"typescript": "2.0.2"
```

}

So anyone can help or share something official and compatible with the final release? I wish the Google people pay attention and take care of the documentations, not everyone is an expert.

Comment: " if it's not up to date then shame on google people " is quite a useless comment.

Comment: 1/3 of your question is pointless ranting. I stopped reading and didn't even get to a part that looks like a question.

Comment: I think u came to my post with bad attitude already , thanks for commenting my friend

Comment: No, the bad attitude started when I read "shame on google people" while you state yourself that you don't even know whose fault it is.

Comment: You are disappointed it can be true but it doesnt mean you should react this way. First think you should understand is that Angular2 is an open source platform and you are not forced to use it. Second thing, Angular2 is not at all easy and you will never understand it fully in one go. If you cant understand anything, you can raise your concern and ask questions on SO, gitter, google group and etc. But man show some respect at least for using it.

Comment: Sir that's my opinion and it's based on experience I had , the official documentation in direction and the final angular 2 release in another direction in the Http part , so what you want me to say ?! praise Google ? I mean it's just reporting an issue and it's kind of healthy criticizing so why you're upset ? the thing is on your profile your's saying that you have "a lot of experiences" in Angular 2 wow I'm impressed because the final release just came out and you have a lot of experience in it ?! ok then try to help me man instead of ..ching me about my opinion !

Comment: With this approach and attitude, no one will think to help you.

Comment: @Max Please edit this question to make it clear what your question is. "so anyone can help or share something official and compatible with the final release ?" is not a clear question. Good questions for Stackoverflow ask for specific code to solve a specific programming issue. If your question cannot be made to fit this description, it will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Seth Difley thanks for the comment my friend but really I don't know edit my question for what ? what is existed in the documentation it's not working with the version of ( node.js & Angular-cli & even typescript)  I downloaded which I believe all r the latest versions that's why I copied that part of my package.json ,  I feel I got bullied just because I expressed my opinion and  maybe because my question has no answer at the moment, like the others jumpin on me because I called google ! to be continue

Comment: really ?! if you guys know how to help then help if not then leave google itself to address what I said if they felt offended by my opinion  my question is very clear to anyone can read and willing to help ! how to access data from web api how to  Create , Read , Update , Delete using Http service ! to be continue ...

Comment: I posted what I did in my code and I was very specific  I don't know what I'm supposed to edit if someone wants to close it just because they don't know how to answer or help to make it clear  then let's be it and again because I guess that's what you referred to and it's like threatening !

Comment: Add your project to git (or similar) and then someone might see where you have gone wrong. Plenty of people have live angular 2 projects using all those things running using the documentation and current published stuff as it stands so 'its googles fault' looks a lot like 'i cant do it which must mean its someone elses fault'. Most people here understand it can be frustrating when you cannot get something to work but a positive attitude can really help... Anyway I hope you get through your issues as I love Angular 2, it has great potential.

Comment: @Matrim thanks my friend and I will consider your suggestion at the moment I'm searching in some ebook and once I figure out something I will come back to post, believe me my attitude is really cool & I do love Angular 2 too and all what I did I expressed my opinion and I didn't know I will get bullied, seems there're some extremist in every field, I really don't care about votes down as long as I want to learn and I know I didn't do something wrong and YES I believe google should do better than this because it's huge company , that's for the bullies and thanks again Matrim and will get back

Answer (score 0):

You must to fix the line:

`import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';`

To:

`import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';`

You missed the `2` ...

Also in `in-memory-data.service.ts` file fix it

There is a mistake in documentation

Comment: I didn't fix everything but still get error which says : 'angular2-in-memory-web-api' has no exported InMemoryWebApiModule, they might even changed the name of the class, I really appreciate brother thanks a lot , do you have any suggestion about the problem with my ASP.NET web Api ? I mean why data wont's show ? if you look at the pic and as I mentioned the once I click on the empty records as they appear in the pic I get undefined in the url : localhost4200/details/undefined  , thanks again bro